# passing 2d float array to a function in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, syntax, parameter-passing

I am trying to pass a 2D array to a function following is my code.

```
float solve(float arr[(nsamples*numImages)+255][256 + nsamples]){
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    nsamples = 100;
    numImages = 5;
    float arr[ (nsamples*numImages)+255][256 + nsamples];
    float res = solve(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

nsamples and numImages are globals. I am getting the following error

```
candidate function not viable: no known conversion from
      'float [(nsamples * numImages) + 255][256 + nsamples]' to 'float (*)[256 +
      nsamples]' for 1st argument
int solve(float arr[(nsamples*numImages)+255][256 + nsamples]){
```

I have tried the variations given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767166/passing-a-2d-array-to-a-c-function) but nothing worked.

Comment: Questions of this sort get asked *every day*. Please search before asking.

Comment: I think you will need to have an integer constant in the second dimension of arr and not `256+nsamples`.

Comment: (@j809) VLA's don't even exist in C++, so both dimensions must be constant expressions.